# How turn on error reporting without reset?

Tags: wp-config

How would I turn on error reporting without resetting the theme? I ask hostgator to help, now my subsite urls are broken.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress error reporting is primarily controlled by [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) and other related constants in `wp-config.php` file. Typically they are completely independent of theme and plugins, although some (well coded) extensions adjust their behavior accordingly with debug settings.

Answer (score 0):

Open wp-config.php in a text editor and instead of

`define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

put

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

This will set PHP display_errors flag on; however plugins and themes might override it.